Android Studio WorkValidationException
I am trying to run my program in Android Studio, and it gives me the following build error:

org.gradle.internal.execution.WorkValidationException: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':processDebugMainManifest' (type 'ProcessApplicationManifest').
- In plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest' property 'mainManifest' specifies file 'C:\Users\charl\AndroidStudioProjects\CMPT276-Term-Project2\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml' which doesn't exist."

So it for some reason tries to find my AndroidManifest.xml under Project2\src\main, where it actually is under Project2\\*app*\src\main. And as far as I know, that location is the correct location and my gradle is looking into a wrong address (which doesn't even exist).
How can I make my Android Studio check in the right location? I have checked my gradle versions, invalidated caches, and restarted the program.
